# Prototype and Jquery conflict

Tags: jquery, prototype, conflict

How to avoid conflict between prototype.js and live search? Now my search is not working correct. If I delete prototype.js my counter is not working, but search is working perfect. How to avoid conflict between prototype and custom.js ? (Custom.js is posted live search code)

```
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script src="js/jquery.ez-bg-resize.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//$.noConflict();
jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) {            // JS for background size
                $("body").ezBgResize({
                    img : "bg.jpg",
                    opacity : 1, 
                    center  : true 
                });

                $("body").fadeIn("slow");

            });
        </script>


<script src="http://sportassveikata.lt/sveikata/js/prototypeplus.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://sportassveikata.lt/sveikata/js/skaic_index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="http://www.kalorijos.lt/js/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://sportassveikata.lt/sveikata/js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And this is live search code:

```
/* JS File */

// Start Ready

jQuery( document ).ready(function( $ ) { 

    // Icon Click Focus
    $('div.icon').click(function(){
        $('input#search').focus();
    });

    // Live Search
    // On Search Submit and Get Results
    function search() {
        var query_value = $('input#search').val();
        $('b#search-string').html(query_value);
        if(query_value !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php",
                data: { query: query_value },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ul#results").html(html);
                }
            });
        }return false;    
    }

    $("input#search").on("keyup", function( e ) {
        // Set Timeout
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

        // Set Search String
        var search_string = $(this).val();

        // Do Search
        if (search_string == '') {
            $("ul#results").fadeOut();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
        }else{
            $("ul#results").fadeIn();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
            $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
        };
    });

});
```

Comment: Use `jQuery.noconflict()`?

Comment: Where? I`ve tryed everywhere... But nothing. Maybe I`m doing something wrong so if you know could you help me and say where should I use noconflict?

Comment: saying "does not work" is not helpful. if you get exceptions then you need to post them. the contents of protoypeplus.js etc are unknown also.